# ¿Como ejecutar una función con boton tomando el id de un *ngFor usando Datatables en Angular?

Tags: html, nodejs, angular, datatables

lo que quiero lograr es obtener el id para ejecutar una función en un boton de una tabla hecha en datatables

tengo el siguiente código en html:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm row-border hover" datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions">

<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>Acciones</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let e of ciudades_List">
        <td>{{ e.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ e.nombre }}</td>
        <td>
            <button (click)="open(content,e.id)" mat-fab color="primary" aria-label="">
                <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
              </button>
            <button mat-fab color="primary" aria-label="" style="background-color:red">
                <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
              </button>
        </td>

    </tr>
</tbody>
```

en la línea donde dice

```
<button (click)="open(content,e.id)" mat-fab color="primary" aria-label="">
```

estoy intentando buscar que sea algo así:

```
<button (click)="open(content,1)" <!-- donde es el quiero poner el id correspondiente -->
```

tengo una tabla anterior sin usar datatables que funciona pero intentando replicar no funciona en datatables.
aquí dejo el código:

```
<div class="mat-elevation-z8">
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>ID</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.id }}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="nombre">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Nombre de la Ciudad</th>
        <td class="padding-table" mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
            {{ element.nombre | uppercase }}
        </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Acciones</th>
        <td class="padding-table" mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
            <button (click)="open(content,element.id)" mat-button class="button_color_primary">
        <mat-icon style="color: white">edit</mat-icon>
      </button> &nbsp;
            <button (click)="Eliminar_Ciudad(content, element.id)" mat-button class="button_color_primary" style="background-color:red">
        <mat-icon style="color: white">delete</mat-icon>
      </button>
        </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>
</table>

<mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]" showFirstLastButtons aria-label="Seleccionar pagina de usuarios.">
</mat-paginator>
```

Aquí dejo el codigo del Ts:

```
mport { Component,OnDestroy,EventEmitter,Input, OnInit, Output, SimpleChanges, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatSort } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { debounceTime } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AlertHelper } from 'src/app/shared/components/helpers/alert.helpers';
import { Ciudad } from 'src/app/shared/models/ciudades.interface';
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { CiudadService } from 'src/app/pages/services/ciudades.service';
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';  


@Component({
  selector: 'app-lista-ciudades',
  templateUrl: './lista-ciudades.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./lista-ciudades.component.css']
})
export class ListaCiudadesComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {


  dtOptions :any = {};
  dtTrigger =new Subject() ;
  
  fileName= 'ciudades.xlsx'; 
  exportexcel(): void 
    {
       let element = document.getElementById('tabla'); 
       const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet =XLSX.utils.table_to_sheet(element);
       const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
       XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, 'Sheet1');
       XLSX.writeFile(wb, this.fileName);
            
    }



  @Input() ciudades_List:Ciudad[]=[];
  @Output() onDebounce: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();
  debouncer: Subject<boolean> = new Subject();

  update_ciudades: Ciudad = {
    id:0,
    nombre:""
  };

  //dataCiudad: Ciudad[] = [];

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['id', 'nombre','actions'];
  
 
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Ciudad>(this.ciudades_List);

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator!: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort!: MatSort;

  
  
  
  constructor(
    private alert:AlertHelper,
    private modalService: NgbModal,
    private ciudadService: CiudadService
  ) { }


  ngOnInit(): void {
    //console.log('la lista de ciudades',this.ciudades_List);
    
    this.debouncer
      .pipe(debounceTime(500))
      .subscribe( valor => {        
        this.onDebounce.emit( valor );
      });

      this.dtOptions = {
        pagingType: 'full_numbers',
        pageLength: 10,
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
      /*
          columns: [{
            title: 'ID',
            data:this.ciudades_List,
          }, {
            title: 'Nombre',
            data: 'nombre'
          },
        
        ],
        */
  
        buttons: [
          'copy', 'excel', 'pdf','print'
        ],
        language: {
          url:'//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.11.3/i18n/es-cl.json'
        }
      };

      this.dtTrigger.next();
  }


  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {

    if(changes.ciudades_List!=undefined){
      if (!changes.ciudades_List.firstChange) {                
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Ciudad>(this.ciudades_List);
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
       
      }
    }
  } 

  open(content:any,id:number) {
    this.update_ciudades.id=id
    this.ciudadService.Obtener_ciudad(id).subscribe(res =>{
      this.update_ciudades.nombre=res.data.nombre;
    })

    this.limpiar_ciudades();
    this.modalService.open(content);

  }

  limpiar_ciudades(){
    this.update_ciudades.nombre=""    
  }

  Actualizar_Ciudades(){  
    if(this.update_ciudades.nombre.trim().length==0){
      this.alert.error_small('Los campos no pueden estar vacios.')
      return
    }

    this.ciudadService.Actualizar_ciudad(this.update_ciudades).subscribe(res =>{
      if (res.success==true) {
            this.alert.success_small(res.msg!)
            this.modalService.dismissAll();
            this.limpiar_ciudades();
            this.debouncer.next( true );
          }else{
            this.alert.error_small(res.msg!)
          }
    })

    
  }

  Eliminar_Ciudad(content:any,id:number){
    this.ciudadService.Eliminar_Ciudad(id).subscribe(res =>{
      if (res.success==true) {
            this.alert.success_small(res.msg!)
            this.debouncer.next( true );
          }else{
            this.alert.error_small(res.msg!)
          }
    })    
  }
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.dtTrigger.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

La aplicación está montada en angular 11.1.4
La versión de node es la 17.1.0

Ya intente Bastantes combinaciones y ninguna me a funcionado correctamente

Comment: no veo que uses en // ts--> open(content,element.id) a content--> utilidad? que error te da

Comment: @nestdan  ya solucione en el ts donde mandaba a llamar a la función open (content:any,id:number) estaba exigiendo que el id sea de tipo number  en vez de eso deje la función (content:any,id:any) y si funciono

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontre el error.
En la función:

```
open(content:any,id:number) {
this.update_ciudades.id=id
this.ciudadService.Obtener_ciudad(id).subscribe(res =>{
  this.update_ciudades.nombre=res.data.nombre;
})
```

Estaba exigiendo que el id fuera de tipo number daba este error

```
Argument of type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

solucione el error cambiando la función en el TS:

```
open(content:any,id:any) {
this.update_ciudades.id=id
this.ciudadService.Obtener_ciudad(id).subscribe(res =>{
  this.update_ciudades.nombre=res.data.nombre;
})
```

dejando el id de tipo **any**

Comment: si bárbaro que  lo pudiste solucionar pero  te comento que en  el las nuevas versiones de Angular hay problemas al usar any Si se puede castear  usando $any()  o también el    non-null assertion operator, !.to suspend strict null and undefined checks https://angular.io/guide/template-expression-operators#any-type-cast-function